# Python only reacts to 'py' command - How to revert to standard?

Tags: python-3.x, windows, terminal

I have no idea what I messed up, but it seems like a lot.

The problem:

*(I am using Windows 10, and only using the "normal" black terminal you get when you type "CMD" into the search.)*

I have installed Python 3.8, and subsequently deleted all older versions (2.6,2.7,3.7) of Python, since I figured I don't need them anymore. Now Python will only work if I type 'py' into the terminal window, 'python' can not find an appropriate command. (Along the way I messed up pip, but this is a different story.)

Is this the "normal" command for Python 3? Did I rename my commands some time in the past? How do I use 'python' again? or should I not?

When I install Python it never asks me how I want to name the command, so I figure installing it one more time will not help.

(Sorry for maybe dumb questions, but this problem seems like one I can solve, before moving on to fixing pip.)

Comment: I suggest installing it one more time. The setup might set up the things you need.

Comment: @MaximMoloshenko Yeah, you should be able to delete your question. If the system doesn't let you, you can mod-flag it and explain why you want it removed. It should get taken down pretty quick :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to check your symbolic links:

`dir /AL /S C:\`

- /A displays all files with a specific attribute, and L specifies reparse points (symlinks and directory junctions)
- /S makes the command recursive

*Replace C:\ with the drive letter you want to scan, or with a path if you don't want to scan an entire drive.*

To delete a symbolic link, you may treat it like any other directory or file.

- If you created a symbolic link to a directory, use the rmdir command.
- If you created a symbolic link to a file, use the del command.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by Andrew Morton in the first comment "Turning it off and on again" helped. I 'repaired' the Python 3.8 installation, and then closed and reopened the terminal window.

Now:

- the 'py' command is gone
- the 'python' command uses python 3.8
- the 'pip3' command finds python again (before it crashed looking for 3.7)

Thanks for the suggestion!